# Subset product & quantum computers, is an instance solvable

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

Suppose you have a quantum computer that can run Shor's algorithm for factorization of integers.

Is it then possible to produce an oracle that determines if no solution exists for an instance of the Subset Product problem, with 100% confidence, in sub-exponential time?

So, the oracle is given a sequence x1, ... xn, as the description of a subset product problem.

It responds either *Yes*, a solution to this instance does not exist, or *No*, a solution to this instance may or may not exist.

If we take he prime factors of all elements in the sequence and then check to see if all of them are present in the target product's factors, this should tell us if a solution is not at all possible. A solution exist may exist if and only if all the prime factors are accounted for. On quantum computers, prime factorization is sub-exponential.

Would like some feedback on if this is correct logic- if it works- and if the complexity is indeed different between classical and quantum systems for this oracle/algorithm. Would also appreciate an explanation on reductions - can Subset Product be reduced to 3SAT without consequence?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theory (try http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I expect that a classical computer could factor everything as much as needed by taking GCDs repeatedly, so I don't think that Shor's algorithm alone is going to help.

Comment: My bad, I avoided cs.stackexchange because it seems geared towards significantly more complex problems. Can this question be converted, or should I re-post it?

Comment: You can flag it and specify a custom reason asking for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm, if I understood it correctly, will fail for the elements `[6, 15]` and the target `10`. It will determine that `6*15 = 2*3*3*5`, which has all of the factors used in `10=2*5`, and incorrectly assert that this means you can make `10` by multiplying `6` and `15`.

There are two reasons that it's unlikely you'll be able to fix this algorithm:

1. [Subset Product is NP-Complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7907/is-the-subset-product-problem-np-complete). Finding a polynomial time quantum algorithm for it, or showing that no such algorithm exists, is probably as hard as determining if P=NP. That is to say, *very very hard*.
2. You don't want the prime factors, you want the "no-need-to-reduce" factors. For example, if every time a number in the problem has a prime factor of `13` it's accompanied by a factor of `17` then there's no need to break `221` into `13*17`. You can apply Euclid's gcd algorithm to various combinations of elements to find these no-need-to-reduce factors, no quantum-ness required.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful. Will post here or message you if I think of questions.

Comment: I've spent more time reformulating and generalizing this question. Do you have any advice on where to send discussions like this? cs.stackexchange?